# using php preg_replace to change html link's href attribute

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace all link href's in a large string with a different URL. With the following code It seems to replace only the 2nd link leaving the first one intact, can someone help me out?

```
$string_of_text = '<a href="http://www.php.net/">PHP</a> <a href="http://www.apache.org/">Apache</a>';
echo preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="(.*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="javascript:alert(\'Test\');"$3>',$string_of_text);
```

Comment: Please fix your question title to describe the question. Take a look at all the rubbish in the "Related" pane on the right of my comment, and don't add to it. :)

Comment: It might be easier to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Lol, I'm sorry Lightness Races in Orbit, I can't see an edit button anywhere however I'll be sure my next question is much more detailed

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of any char `.` use any not (^) quote `[^"]`

```
echo preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="javascript:alert(\'Test\');"$3>',$string_of_text);
```

Comment: @JoopEggen , i have nearly similar problem. i have an array of links containing id params, and another array of ids. i want to replace all link's href attribute of the first array that have the same ids in the second array.... sorry for my grammar, if incorrect!!!

Comment: @user8009 (no sorry neeeded - hey, I am esperantist: English = gcd, Esperanto = lcm) Maybe put a question in SO with some more details. There exists a regex replace applying a function for replacement: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php maybe that could be used in your case.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the greedy operator in your regex like this:

```
'/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modifications to Aurelio De Rosa's answer:

```
'/<a(.*?)href=(["\'])(.*?)\\2(.*?)>/i'
```