# Replace any link to specify variable

Tags: php, regex

I have to replace any link in string to specify variable. I have a code

```
$intro = $this->item->introtext;
```

this code retrun me for example this

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a href="/upload/dzialanosc-spoleczna/Mikolajki-w-Dabiu-2012/MG_0187.jpg">
<img width="700" height="467" alt="" src="/upload/dzialanosc-spoleczna/Mikolajki-w-Dabiu-2012/MG_0187s.jpg">
</a>
</p>
```

I have to replace this anchor href by own variable (new generated link) for example **$link**

Comment: I found the best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058158/using-php-preg-replace-to-change-html-links-href-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this...

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a href="<?php
$index = 0;
$link = 'YourLink';
if($index==0){
//default
echo '/upload/dzialanosc-spoleczna/Mikolajki-w-Dabiu-2012/MG_0187.jpg';
}else{
echo $link;
}
?>">
<img width="700" height="467" alt="" src="/upload/dzialanosc-spoleczna/Mikolajki-w-Dabiu-2012/MG_0187s.jpg">
</a>
</p>
```

I hope that's what you want :-)

Comment: Than you, but I can't create this string in other way. I have to modify him.